# Expresión regular para encontrar palabras contenidas dentro de dos caracteres

Tags: python

Tengo un inquietud, intento crear una expresión regular para encontrar palabras o cualquier tipo de caracteres contenidos dentro de otros dos, ejemplo:

```
<hola>
(hola)
[hola]
{hola}
```

-

```
texto = "csec872(hola)7bjaaae43fanca<hola>lnx23DXA"
```

Finalmente lo que pretendo es encontrar ese contenido y eliminarlo junto con los paréntesis o corchetes. (intento resolver esto usando python 2.7)

Comment: ¿Puede aparecer anidadas esas expresiones? Por ejemplo `"texto<otro texto (anidado {y mas}) sigue> aqui"`. Eso complicaría mucho las cosas, sobre todo si las partes anidadas pueden usar los mismos delimitadores que las más exteriores, es decir `"por (ejemplo (asi))"`

Comment: no creo que para mi caso aparezcan anidadas, solo que pueden aparecer a lo largo del string sin estar anidadas.

Answer (score 1):

Una expresión regular podría ser la siguiente:

```
(\(.*?\)|{.*?}|<.*?>|\[.*?\])
```

Que se interpreta así:

- Es un grupo (el que todo vaya entre paréntesis así lo indica) con cuatro posibilidades (separadas por la barra `|`):

  1. Cualquier texto entre paréntesis
  2. Cualquier texto entre llaves
  3. Cualquier texto entre ángulos
  4. Cualquier texto entre corchetes

En los cuatro casos, a la hora de definir "cualquier texto" he usado `.*?` que significa una secuencia compuesta de cero o más caracteres, sean estos los que sean, pero lo más corta posible que haga cumplir la expresión regular (el `*?` indica que el *matching* debe ser *non-greedy*). Por defecto los matching son *greedy* que significa que intentan encajar con el máximo de caracteres posible. En este caso no queremo esto, pues `"un (ejemplo) como (este)"` encajaría desde el primer `(` hasta el último `)`, y queremos que lo haga sólo hasta el siguiente.

Esa expresión regular se usaría como parte de un `re.sub()` para sustituir todas los *matching* por una cadena vacía. Ejemplo:

```
import re

texto = "csec872(hola)7bjaaae43fanca<hola>lnx23DXA"
resultado = re.sub(r"(\(.*?\)|{.*?}|<.*?>|\[.*?\])", "", texto)
print(resultado)
```

```
csec8727bjaaae43fancalnx23DXA
```

**Observación**. Esta solución aún funciona  si los paréntesis, llaves, corchetes o ángulos aparecen anidados, *pero son de diferente tipo*, como por ejemplo: `"Esto [es (un {ejemplo} con) cosas] anidadas"`, pues el patrón que detecta "algo entre corchetes" tomaría todo lo que está contenido entre el `[` y el `]`, lo que para tu objetivo de eliminarlo todo, funcionará.

Fallará en cambio si aparecen expresiones anidadas con delimitadore *del mismo tipo* como por ejemplo `"Esto (es un (ejemplo) con) cosas) anidadas"`, pues en ese caso el patrón "algo entre paréntesis" encajará con `(es un (ejemplo)`, que no es lo que queremos.